# Create pointer to boost asio tcp socket

Tags: c++, sockets, pointers, boost, tcp

### What I'm trying to make

I'm working on a library that connects to a piece of hardware over TCP. The library provides some functions for setting parameters on the remote hardware. To make this library easy to use I want the connect function to create a connection state `struct` / object, a pointer to which will be held by the software calling using this class. That way it can connect to multiple targets at once and have the handles for each connection to pass to the other functions of the library.

Here is the relevant source code:

```
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

struct connection_state {
    boost::asio::io_service *io_service;
    tcp::socket *socket;
    bool connected = false;
};

__stdcall int connect(void **state, const char *host, int port) {
    // create connection state object
    struct connection_state *s = (connection_state *)calloc(1, sizeof(struct connection_state));
    if (!s) {
        // we did not get the memory
        return -ENOMEM;
    }
    // bend the state pointer to point to our new object
    *state = (void *)s;
    // create ioservice object and put it in state
    s->io_service = new boost::asio::io_service();
    // create socket and put it in state
    s->socket = new tcp::socket(s->io_service); // THIS LINE FAILS
    // create resolver on stack
    tcp::resolver resolver(s->io_service);
    // create query
    tcp::resolver::query query(host, std::to_string(port));
    tcp::resolver::iterator itt;
    // resolve IP / hostname
    itt = resolver.resolve(query);
    // connect!
    boost::asio::connect(s->socket, itt);
    // we are now connected!
    s->connected = true;
    return 0;
}
```

This code is based on the [example TCP client](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime1.html) from the boost documentation, but I'm trying to have the `socket` and `io_service` objects in some form of object I can pass around.

### My Problem

This fails to build with:

```
pc/PC.cpp: In function ‘int connect(void**, const char*, int)’: 
pc/PC.cpp:67:44: error: no matching function for call to 
‘boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::basic_stream_socket(boost::asio::io_service*&)’
 s->socket = new tcp::socket(s->io_service); // THIS LINE FAILS
                                          ^
```

I don't really know why I'm unable to create a new `tcp::socket` this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ‘boost::asio::basic_stream_socket::basic_stream_socket(boost::asio::io_service*&)’

It says you're passing the `io_service` as a pointer. Don't.

```
s->socket = new tcp::socket(*(s->io_service));
```

Better yet, ***don't use `new` or `delete`¹ in c++***

(¹ worse, `malloc`/`free`)

Comment: Right, dereferencing fixed it. As for the new / malloc / calloc, what would be the nice way to create an object the lifetime of which I don't yet know otherwise? I could move all of this into a class, but I'd still need to create an instance of it with `new` and delete it in the disconnect function.

Comment: Well, C++ is not like C. Here's [what I'd do in C++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd9b98f94ed561ec). You can "pimpl" split that implementation: https://wandbox.org/permlink/rAf5rbkfoYIdJDXl

Comment: You can of course make the type totally transparent ("C" style, but that loses RAII)

Comment: that looks nice, but the problem is, that function is an interface of a library, which will be called (among others) from C, so I can't really export that connction_handle type. That's why I made it void so the calling function doesn't have to know about the actual type.

Comment: Ah I just got what you meant with the 2nd comment, I can cast the result of `connection_handle::create();` to void.

Comment: Of course, you don't have to make it `void` for that to happen: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZcuYThuvDhsEHQqF (look at `connection.h` there)